# How to pass json data as key with res.render()

Tags: node.js, json, express

im a new to nodejs and trying to send json data to index.pug to get rendered. The json file is in the root directory and the index.pug receiving the data is in a views folder. The json is an array

```
{
  "profiles": [
    {    },
    {    }
  ]
}
```

in my .js file  i make the following to include the json file

```
const people = require('./people.json');
```

and i am trying to render it as follow

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.render('index', {
    title: 'Homepage',
    people.profiles
  });
});
```

but i am getting an ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

thanks for helping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following JSON key-value format.

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.render('index', {
    title: 'Homepage',
    profiles: people.profiles
  });
});
```

Let's say your JSON file is like

```
{
  "profiles": [
    {    },
    {    }
  ]
}
```

We are sending here the profiles array, So in your pug file, you can access the profile array

```
ul
  each profile in profiles
    li= profile
```